# Mid of Polyline into a Point Feature in Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to write a python script to determine flow direction on a water pipe network. I've used this script to find the mid point along each polyline, now i need to convert this data into a point feature class, which will become an arrow of flow direction.

I've tried saving it as a list but cannot convet the list to a point feature. Can anyone suggest ways to save the mid point locations as a point feature class?

```
#FlowArrows.py
import arcpy
#setting the environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "J:/PYTHON/Flow_Direction.gdb"
#arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Setting the containers
Pipes = r"J:\PYTHON\Flow_Direction.gdb\Pipes"
Nodes = r"J:\PYTHON\Flow_Direction.gdb\Nodes"
MidList = []

#Getting the mid point
Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(Pipes)
    for i in Cursor:
    Midpoint = i.shape.positionAlongLine(0.50,True).firstPoint
    MidList.append(Midpoint)

print ("done")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import arcpy, os
Pipes = r"H:\My Documents\GDB.gdb\Pipes"
MidList = []

Cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(Pipes)
for i in Cursor:
    Midpoint = i.shape.positionAlongLine(0.50,True).firstPoint
    point = arcpy.Point(Midpoint.X, Midpoint.Y)
    pointGeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
    MidList.append(pointGeom)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(MidList, os.path.join(os.path.split(Pipes)[0], "Nodes"))
```